# On ' npm test login.component.spect.ts ' , it says Cannot find module '@app/store/user/user.actions' from 'login.component.ts'

Tags: unit-testing, ngrx

I am new to Ngrx and its UnitTesting , Can anyone help me with the best tutorial or link to learn
I am facing an error ,
On  ' npm test login.component.spect.ts ' , it says
Cannot find module '@app/store/user/user.actions' from 'login.component.ts' , in Testbed how to import actions and reducer file

Though i've imported the action and reducer file in spec and Ts file , still i am getting an above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to define your `paths` inside the `tsconfig.spec.json`.
If you're using jest you also have to define some `moduleNameMapper`s.